# Trying to replace '_' with user input values, works fine except at index 0

Tags: python, list, random

```
import random
# making a list with word_list
word_list = ['Lemon', 'Apple', 'Kiwi']

#picking random word
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

print(f'the solution is {chosen_word}.')
display = []
word_length = len(chosen_word)
for _ in range(word_length):
    display += '_'
print(display)

end_of_game = False
while not end_of_game:
    guess = input('Guess the letter: ').lower()
    for position in range(word_length):
        letter = chosen_word[position]
        if letter == guess:
            display[position] = letter
    print(display)
    if '_' not in display:
        end_of_game == True
        print('You win')
```

For example, if chosen word is "Apple" and guess from user is 'A', it shows "A _ _ _ _". I need to fill all the spaces with correct letters, but what I am getting is all letters other than the letter at index 0.

Comment: please, could you format your code appropriately?

Comment: The letter at index `0` is capitalized so it will never equal `input('Guess the letter: ').lower()` which is explicitly converting to lowercase. Maybe you meant `letter = chosen_word[position].lower()`?

Comment: Anyway, `letter` should be fed in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.lower()` on the input given by the user, but the word that it is being compared with has an upper case letter at the start, hence `letter = chosen_word[position]` can never be `True`, for the first letter.

You can fix this by comparing the given input with the lowercase version of the `chosen_word`:

```py
for position in range(word_length):
    letter = chosen_word[position]
    if letter.lower() == guess:
        display[position] = letter
```

should work.

Comment: unless you care for case. Then you would not want to use `.lower` in first place.

Comment: Yes, absolutely! Though, given the context of a word guessing game, I'm assuming that the case doesn't matter :)